# compare few elements in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two list of tuples like shown in following order:

```
a = [(18, 299, 70, 33), (18, 323, 70, 34), 
(18, 448, 70, 35), (18, 548, 70, 36), (18, 613, 70, 37)]

b = [(18, 223, 70, 37), (18, 299, 70, 38), 
(18, 323, 70, 39), (18, 448, 70, 40), (18, 548, 70, 41), (18, 613, 70, 42)]
```

**What I want:**

1). I am trying to print elements which are in `b` but not in `a`

2). I want to compare the above shown lists in such a manner that only first three elements of individual tuples are compared irrespective of non-matching last element of that tuple i.e. `37`, `38`, `39`.... So in above case I want my answer to look like:

```
result = [(18,223,70,37)]
```

So as you can see in this case the algorithm would totally ignore the last number or 4th element while comparing individual tuples. Hence I want that if the first three elements of tuples are matched then it can predict that there is no difference even though fourth element may or may not be same.

**What I tried:**

Apart from searching solutions I just wanted to try `set(b_value)-set(a_value)` approach. But I knew it wont work as the result generated by this looks like this:

`set([(18, 613, 70, 42), (18, 448, 70, 40), (18, 548, 70, 41), (18, 299, 70, 38), (18, 323, 70, 39), (18, 223, 70, 37)])`

This is pretty obvious result as the last element of all the tuples are not matching hence this method predicts all such tuples as unmatched.

**EDIT:** 
I would like to retain the value of 4th element in my result, so deleting all 4th element in all tuples and comparing is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Produce a set for the first list containing the tuples without the last element; you can do a second loop over `b` to collect those whose first elements are not in the set:

```
a_set = {t[:-1] for t in a}
result = [t for t in b if t[:-1] not in a_set]
```

Algorithmically speaking, this does the same amount of work as converting both to sets and producing a set difference.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [(18, 299, 70, 33), (18, 323, 70, 34), 
... (18, 448, 70, 35), (18, 548, 70, 36), (18, 613, 70, 37)]
>>> b = [(18, 223, 70, 37), (18, 299, 70, 38), 
... (18, 323, 70, 39), (18, 448, 70, 40), (18, 548, 70, 41), (18, 613, 70, 42)]
>>> a_set = {t[:-1] for t in a}
>>> [t for t in b if t[:-1] not in a_set]
[(18, 223, 70, 37)]
```

Comment: this is perfect. Thanks Martijin.